# XSLT- Creating Parent XML element

Tags: xslt

I've fairly recently started learning XSLT after getting to grips with XML and XPath; I'm trying to complete a practice exercise; I think I'm nearly there but I've ran into a problem. So I have the following XML document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
<a>
    <b></b>
    <b></b>
    <b></b>
    <b></b>
</a>
</root>
```

And I'd like to surround the  elements with a pair of  parent elements (to output the following):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
<a>
  <b-group>
    <b></b>
    <b></b>
    <b></b>
    <b></b>
  <b-group>
</a>
```

Here is my XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
version="2.0">

<xsl:template match="root">
    <xsl:element name="root">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="a">
    <xsl:element name="a">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="b">
    <xsl:element name="b-group">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="b">
    <xsl:element name="b">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Despite making several other attempts, I'm having difficulty creating the pair of  elements that surround the  elements; could anyone point me in the right direction of how to do this please?

Comment: Can there be other child elements of `a` elements than those `b` elements you want to wrap into a `b-group`? In general your whole approach is rather wordy and unnecessary, and for the grouping there is `for-each-group`, if needed.

Comment: "*I'd like to surround the elements with a pair of parent elements*" You mean a pair of *tags*. There is only one *element*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do this in the template matching `a`, for example:

```
<xsl:template match="a">
    <a>
        <b-group>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="b"/>
        </b-group>
    </a>
</xsl:template>
```

**Additional notes**:

Use a *literal result element* to create an element whose name is known, instead of `xsl:element`.

Most of your templates do the same thing: create an element with the same name as the one being matched, and apply templates to its children. Thus they could be consolidated into one. A template like this is known as the [identity transform template](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform) and it is commonly used when most of the document needs to preserved as is, with only a few modifications. This would reduce your entire stylesheet to just:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="a">
    <a>
        <b-group>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="b"/>
        </b-group>
    </a>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```